# How do I check whether the table contains null value or not in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have tried this. Is this correct?

```
#standardSQL
with table1 as(
SELECT "somename" name,"someaddress" as adrs UNION ALL
SELECT null name,null UNION ALL
SELECT null name,null
)
SELECT sum(array_length(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(table1),"null[,}]")))no_of_nulls from table1
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use this approach? How many columns does your table have? Are you trying to check for the existence of *any* null value, or to get the count of them?

Comment: counting null values

Comment: What about the other two questions?

Comment: table1 is an example table. The pattern null[,}] doesn't match with the word nullable or any other word containing null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still unclear from the question and comments, but assuming that you have just a few columns, list them explicitly as part of a query to count the NULL values:

```
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT "somename" AS name,"someaddress" AS adrs UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL
)
SELECT COUNTIF(name IS NULL) + COUNTIF(adrs IS NULL) AS null_count
FROM table1
```

This is more efficient than converting to JSON and applying a regular expression to the result.